# critical dependency the request of a dependency is an expression React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, react-hooks

I have an issue in my code, for any reason the Webpack is not letting me to import images dynamically:

The used hook "useImage.js":

```
import React from 'react'

const useImage = (fileName) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true)
    const [error, setError] = React.useState(null)
    const [image, setImage] = React.useState(null)

    React.useEffect(() => {
        const fetchImage = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await import(fileName) // change relative path to suit your needs
                setImage(response)
            } catch (err) {
                setError(err)
            } finally {
                setLoading(false)
            }
        }

        fetchImage()
    }, [fileName])

    return {
        loading,
        error,
        image,
    }
}

export default useImage;
```

The current component "Project":

```
import React from "react";

import "@styles/project.css";

import useImage from "@hooks/useImage"

const Project = ({project}) => {
    const {loading, error, image} = useImage("@images/JavaScript Practice/main.png");

    return (
        <div className="project">
            {loading
                    ? <p>Loading</p>
                    : <img src={image} className="project__img" alt="Image of the product" id="image" />
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Project;
```

The error:
[image]

At this point I really do not understand what is wrong, I have tried many things and nothing works, I hope that one of you has an idea of a solution. Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: Webpack doesn't support that kind of dynamic import usage, cause at compile time it doesn't know what or where you're trying to import that image from. And from its point of view you just have a hook with a string. Check [here](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import)